# Reference list: Suppressing dots after companies names using biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{Test.bib} 

\begin{document}

Test cite \parencite{Duden.2014}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I want to cite:

```
@Misc{Duden.2014,
  Title                    = {{E}valuation},

  Author                   = {Duden},
  Year                     = {2014},

  Url                      = {http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Evaluation},
  Urldate                  = {2014-06-18}
}
```

In the bibliography, it results in (ignore the a, it's due to multiple citing of Duden):

[image]

How can I eliminate the unwanted dot after Duden? The problem occurs in all the specific cases of not citing an author like Mustermann, M. (2014).... but citing a company/institution.

Comment: If you're strictly following APA style, the period is supposed to be there.

Comment: See the "Organization as Author" section: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/06/

Comment: Jep, but in my case it's not strictly APA, even tough I really dislike setting up special rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the APA style that redefines `author` bib macro that adds this full stop, so we have to re-redefine it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, firstinits = false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}
@Misc{Duden.2014,
  Title                    = {{E}valuation},

  Author                   = {Duden},
  Year                     = {2014},

  Url                      = {http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Evaluation},
  Urldate                  = {2014-06-18}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}\newblock%% <- Changed here
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}

\begin{document}

Test cite \parencite{Duden.2014}.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]